# Implementing a gradient function using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement a specific gradient function with NumPy. I am sure my math is correct, but I have failed at coding it. I have attached my work and the parts of the code to be edited.

[image: My attempt and the correct gradient]

[image: The blank template]

I have tried attempting to understand how numpy arrays work, but this hasn't taken me anywhere.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)